# pip keeps installing wrong version of six module

Tags: python, pip, six

I'm using installing six on MacOS,

```
%> pip install six --user --upgrade
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.4.1
```

And I confirmed it later with

```
%> python -c "import six; print six.__version__"
1.4.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the last statement print?

Comment: @cel 1.4.1 updated question

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165#issuecomment-145856429